# Search filter not reset jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a the search filter attribute to my jquery mobile app like this:

```
data-filter="true"
```

When i type in the search bar and it automatically filters the posts I need, I click on one of the articles but when I return back to homepage it only displays the filter and not reload the entire content.

The is my homepage button code:

```
<li><a href="#blog" class="p_ft">Home</a></li>
```

How do I get around this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the filter every time the homepage is about to be shown:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#blog", function() {
    $(this).find(".ui-listview-filter input").val("").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frederic, i have seen this while reading the jquery mobile doc but where do i add this in my code?

Comment: @Isaac, since the event is delegated to `document`, it does not really matter where you put that code. You can add it to your existing JS code pretty much wherever you want.

Comment: you are a star :). I started as a programmer 10years ago then was working on vb6 but stopped after 1yr since it wasn't challenging and ended up as a computer engineer.

Now I am returning back to it with emergence of mobile phones and apps and would need your guide on where to start from and what training videos to listen to. I have already paid for lynda.com and learning from their site for a start.

Thanks